# Cassandra - Per CF Partitioner

Tags: cassandra

I want to know if we can change the partitioner on per CF basis on the same keyspace. I want to do this because I have data on *some* CFs that is already hashed with murmur3 and this hash result *is* my partition key, and I want to avoid cassandra to perform the hash of my hash just to produce another number for the partitioning when it could simply just use mine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and you cannot change a partitioner. Once set the cluster is permanently tied to it. Murmur3 is fast and there really isn't any concerned about the hash of the hash, you should still end up with balanced cluster.

Comment: Thanks, balanced cluster is not my concern. Alleviate some CPU is. I had a look at the Murmur3Partitioner, it seems it is hard to tell that partitioner (or a custom one) that the key received is relative to a specific CF. I have to peek a bit deeper on that.

Comment: the murmur3 partitioner will not be the cpu bottleneck I can assure you. More likely (by a lot) it will be something like sorting clustering indexes (more so on collections), compression, auth (depending on setup), backpressure on flushes, or not keeping up with compaction or poor data model causing too much IO on reads.